# I don't know why my ajax code returns a 404 error although the url is okay

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

Ajax returns a 404 error code and it's not a cross-domain problem.

I want to do an ajax request in a TIZEN Web application project, to my WebService which has functions that I need to use in the TIZEN project.
Originally, the xhr.status was 0, and it changed to 404 by solving a cross domain problem. The URL parameter is accurate.

What's the problem?

```
$.ajax({
    crossOrigin:true
    , type: "POST"
    , url: "http://ip/web projeect/web source/function"
    , data: null
    , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    , dataType: "json"
    , async: false
    , success: function (jSonResult) {


    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
     console.log(xhr.status);
     console.log(eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")"));
    }
});
```

Issue:

```
app.js (154) :404
app.js (155) :undefined
```

Comment: When I copy the url from your code into the address bar the browser tells me that the IP of `서버ip` could not be resolved.

Comment: that's just a string not meaningful.

Comment: Can you show your route config?

Answer (score 0):

Yuor url has spaces in it which could be causing problems.  Try replacing with hyphens like so:

before: "http://ip/web projeect/web source/function"
after:  "http://ip/web-projeect/web-source/function"

Comment: Url what i want to use is on my company's intranet. You cannot access there so I put a meaningless stuff on this question. I tested itself on developer tool(f12) and my url is no problem. I wanna know why I cannot go there on another web application.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the url is on your intranet. Is that url accessible from your application? Try and check it directly from where the application is hosted. Also, check the CORS domains and ensure they are correct.